# Odd behavior without virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I am working on a piece of code that presents a very odd behavior. I managed to replicate it in a simple hello world style program, following is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    virtual ~Test() = default;

protected:
    virtual void SetUp() { }
};

class ICallbackReceiver
{
public:
    virtual ~ICallbackReceiver() = default;
    virtual void onReady() = 0;
};

// C-style callback
void readyReceiver(void* userdata)
{
    cout << "3) readyReceiver\n";
    static_cast<ICallbackReceiver*>(userdata)->onReady();
}

using callback_t = void(*)(void*);
callback_t myCallback;
void* myUserData;

void registerCallback(callback_t callback, void* userData)
{
    cout << "2) registerCallback\n";
    myCallback = callback;
    myUserData = userData;
}

class ConfigurableTest : public /*virtual*/ Test, public ICallbackReceiver
{
public:

    void SetUp() override
    {
        cout << "1) ConfigurableTest::SetUp\n";
        registerCallback(&readyReceiver, static_cast<void*>(this));
    }

    void onReady() override
    {
        cout << "4) ConfigurableTest::onReady\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    ConfigurableTest test;
    test.SetUp();

    myCallback(myUserData);

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever `myCallback` is called something has to be tested. And this is the output that should be displayed:

```
1) ConfigurableTest::SetUp
2) registerCallback
3) readyReceiver
4) ConfigurableTest::onReady
```

But, unless I specify a `virtual` inheritance for the `Test` class, this is the output that I see:

```
1) ConfigurableTest::SetUp
2) registerCallback
3) readyReceiver
1) ConfigurableTest::SetUp
2) registerCallback
```

As you can see `ConfigurableTest::onReady` is never called, but `ConfigurableTest::SetUp` is actually called twice!

What is the origin of this behavior? How can I re-factor the code to reproduce the correct behavior without using `virtual` inheritance?

Comment: What compiler did you use? Anyway, replicated on `g++.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 7.2.0`

Comment: @underscore_d `g++ 5.4.0` compiled with `-std=c++11`

Comment: I can also replicate it by not using `C++11` (with minor changes to the code).

Comment: Good point: I was compiling with `-std=c++14`.

Comment: This works as expected if `ICallbackReceiver *` is put in place of `void *`.  Maybe some type information is getting lost.

Comment: @dbush I cannot change the `C` callback.

Comment: @Nick I expected as much.  Just trying to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you make conversions `ConfigurableTest` -> `void *` -> `ICallbackReceiver`, what is not permitted. You need to convert to the same type `ConfigurableTest` back from `void *` - no error in this case.

See also [multiple inheritance: unexpected result after cast from void * to 2nd base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379427/multiple-inheritance-unexpected-result-after-cast-from-void-to-2nd-base-class)