# Casting a void* to super classes of multple inherited class doesn't call the right method

Tags: c++, casting, multiple-inheritance, void-pointers

I'm storing into a container a list of pointers to an heterogeneous set of objects, using a string to identify them. Regarding the safety of this operation, I've already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200669/cast-void-to-classes-with-multiple-inheritance) and I'm fine with that.

The problem is that when the class has multiple inheritance and I try to cast the same pointer to either one or the other super class, it seems that the second cast fails.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  virtual void hello() = 0;
};

class B {
public:
  virtual void goodbye() = 0;
};

class C : public A,
          public B
{
public:
  void hello() override {
    std::cout << "C says: Hello World!" << std::endl;
  }
  void goodbye() override {
    std::cout << "C says: GoodBye World!" << std::endl;
  }
};

class D : public A {
public:
  void hello() override {
    std::cout << "D says: Hello World!" << std::endl;
  }
};

class E : public B {
public:
  void goodbye() override {
    std::cout << "E says: GoodBye World!" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::map <std::string, void*> mymap;

  C c;
  D d;
  E e;

  mymap["C"] = (void*) &c;
  mymap["D"] = (void*) &d;
  mymap["E"] = (void*) &e;

  static_cast<A*>(mymap["D"])->hello();
  static_cast<B*>(mymap["E"])->goodbye();
  static_cast<A*>(mymap["C"])->hello();
  static_cast<B*>(mymap["C"])->goodbye();

  return 0;
}
```

The expected output would be:

```
D says: Hello World!
E says: GoodBye World!
C says: Hello World!
C says: GoodBye World!
```

but what I get instead is:

```
D says: Hello World!
E says: GoodBye World!
C says: Hello World!
C says: Hello World!
```

I don't even know how is that possible since I'm not even calling `hello`.

**EDIT**
After understanding what has been discussed in the *duplicate of* and this page, I've ended up with this solution:

```
int main()
{
  std::map <std::string, void*> mymap;

  C c;
  D d;
  E e;

  mymap["C"] = static_cast<A*>(&c);
  mymap["D"] = static_cast<A*>(&d);
  mymap["E"] = static_cast<B*>(&e);

  static_cast<A*>(mymap["D"])->hello();
  static_cast<B*>(mymap["E"])->goodbye();
  static_cast<A*>(mymap["C"])->hello();
  dynamic_cast<B*>(static_cast<A*>(mymap["C"]))->goodbye();

  return 0;
}
```

An alternative solution that I've found is also making the second class inherit from the previous:

```
...
class B : public A{
public:
  virtual void goodbye() = 0;
};

class C : public B
{
public:
  void hello() override {
    std::cout << "C says: Hello World!" << std::endl;
  }
  void goodbye() override {
    std::cout << "C says: GoodBye World!" << std::endl;
  }
};
...
int main()
{
  std::map <std::string, void*> mymap;

  C c;
  D d;

  mymap["C"] = static_cast<A*>(&c);
  mymap["D"] = static_cast<A*>(&d);

  static_cast<A*>(mymap["D"])->hello();
  static_cast<A*>(mymap["C"])->hello();
  dynamic_cast<B*>(static_cast<A*>(mymap["C"]))->goodbye();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Much smaller testcase with irrelevant things taken out](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77272e768a094bad) - the lack of output is telling. There's UB here somewhere...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, as discussed in the previous question, if the string is correct and I know exactly what I'm casting to, the operation is safe. This question is different since there are two superclasses now. I don't understand why if I cast the same pointer to either one or the other super class I don't get the correct function called. The code is of course much more complex than that and I didn't find a "well-defined approach" to the general problem I have, which is out of scope for this discussion anyways.

Comment: Perhaps this can help intuition: if you have `C c;` and you try to print the addresses of `(A*)&c` and `(B*)&c` you will get two different values, corresponding to the two subobjects. The compiler adjusted the pointer using the right offset since the compiler knows we are converting `C*` to `A*` and `B*`. If we move through `void *` we prevent the compiler to perform the adjustment -- hence the UB. If you cast `C*` to `void*`, you then need to cast it back to `C*`, after which you can cast again to `A*` and `B*`, if you want.

Answer (score 5):

Your code has undefined behaviour.

Given a `void*` converted to `B*`, there is no way for the computer to know where (in the pointed-to thing that is actually a `C`) the `B` subobject is. You're just pretending that the whole thing (or, at least, a prefix of it) is a `B`, which would be true if it were a simple single inheritance… but yours isn't; the first base is an `A`, not a `B`.

Don't erase types with `void*` like this.

Comment: I would add to this answer, that if you want to maintain the class inheritance structure, you might want to have a superclass that is the parents of all of them, so you could write `std::map <std::string, Parent*> mymap;`. Don't take this as a solution, it is an idea that might work.

Comment: Yes that is a good idea - add in some `dynamic_cast` for the win

Comment: @VictorHMartin I've already hoped for that solution with the Parent, but unfortunately the original classes are templated and there is no assumption that all the template parameter can have a common ancestor. I've just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702235/c-stdmap-holding-any-type-of-value), it looks like what I'm trying to do is type erasure, so I would need to use `std::any`. Btw the original code is open source and is [here](https://github.com/ori-drs/pronto_core/blob/master/pronto_ros/include/pronto_ros/ros_frontend.hpp#L127).